# using swing components

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jeditorpane

User enters a value in `JFormattedText`, I need to get this value and put it in class definition

```
private static final int x = <here must be entered variable>;
```

And how to put `System.out.println` result to `JTextArea` (  or maybe I should use another component?)

Comment: Please explain properly. I am unable to understand your question.

Comment: please explain your question well.

Comment: I don't think you have read the Swing tutorial yet. You got the link to the tutorial on your last posting. So read the tutorial and download the working examples to get the basics.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final int x = <here must be entered variable>;
```

No way. You can't assign a user entered value to a static final field. `private static final` is the Java way of declaring a system wide constant value.

Answer (score 0):

> ANd how to put system.outprinln result to JtextArea

See the [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for one way.